# Possibility of Alternative URLs

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

What would the process be to change our URL to something more "snappy" than networkengineering.stackexchange.com?

10+ syllables is quite a mouthful to use when attempting to get the word out to friends and colleagues about ANY website. Especially one with a somewhat esoteric subject matter.

I know that there are many other options for a URL out there, and this question is not meant for a community debate on one URL versus another URL.

Is it possible to do something like neteng.se (or any other example you can think of) which is less than 10 syllables now that we're leaving Beta status?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a really well-established abbreviation that so engrained in the community norm that a significant number of users are likely to try it before the "full name", we generally do not abbreviate names just for the sake of removing a few keystrokes. We haven't seen anything like that here.

With bookmarks, hot linking, and text completion, it is increasing uncommon for someone to have to type out the full name everyday anyway.

Comment: My primary concern was not keystrokes but word of mouth.  This is how I've been driving colleagues to the site, and attempting to grow our professional user base.

Comment: Also, it eats up characters in links you add to comments.  I might have a [single](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/451/being-a-more-open-community) word link, but behind it is 57 characters of theallotted 600~ in a comment, nearly 10%.   I dont want to always have to use a third party url shortener.